# Can one construct a left-invariant vector field on SO(3)?

Tags: differential-geometry

Here's my understanding:

Elements of $SO(3)$ can be identified with points on a sphere $S^2$, by fixing an identity element in $S^2$ in euclidean space at some arbitrary distance from the origin, and letting the action of $SO(3)$ define the rest of the points of $S^2$.

I am trying to picture a left invariant vector field on $S^2$ which is invariant under all actions of $SO(3)$, i.e. any composition of a rotation in one axis, followed by a rotation in a second axis.

However, I can't help think that action of the pushforward $lg_*$: $T(SO(3))$ --> $T(SO(3))$ along one axis of a left invariant vector field on $SO(3)$ yielding $lg_*(X_e) = (X_g)$ is like the parallel transport of a vector in the tangent space of e in $SO(3)$ along one particular direction (my mistake probably lies here). However, the parallel transport of a vector along two seperate directions, when they intersect, in general yields vectors of different direction. This is like saying the pushforward, for elements of $SO(3)$, $k = gh = fj$, that $$X_k = X_{gh} = (lg_*  \circ lh_*) (X_e) = (lf_* \circ lj_*) (X_e) = X_{fj} = X_k$$ which is a contradiction.

I have thought that maybe the issue is solved only by imagining that the tangent space to $SO(3)$ can only be pictured in higher dimensions, but was hoping someone could give me some hints on this.

Comment: $SO(3)$ cannot be identified with $S^2$. There is a *map* $SO(3) \to S^2$, given by fixing $x \in S^2$ and sending $A \mapsto Ax$, but it has a circle's worth of $A$ for each $x$.

Comment: It should be antipodal pairs of points in $\mathbb S^3,$ those being the group of unit quaternions.

Comment: I see...! I have narrowmindedly thought that the action of SO(3) is on a SINGLE point of the sphere, and therefore was of dimension 2, when in fact it acts on all points, and is of dimension 3. This can be seen from the fact that there are two dimensions worth of rotations (degrees of freedom) to fix the first element of the orthonormal basis and 1 dimension more to fix the second element, giving a total of 3.

Comment: @Rascalniikov if you want someone to be notified that you have written a comment for them, you need to start the comment with an "at" sign and their username, at least the first three letters, as I have done here. Since it is directly after your question, you are notified whether I do this or not. Meanwhile, given a vector $v,$ meaning a quaternion with real part $0,$ and a unit quaternion $q,$ we get a rotated vector (quaternion with real coefficient $0$) from $q v \bar{q}.$ The two to one aspect is that $-q$ accomplishes the same rotation as $q.$

Comment: @will jagy     Alright thanks for pointing that out. I have not studied quarternions but I know that they are related to symmetries and lie groups, and I suppose this problem of representing rotations about a vector's own axis (reminding me of the spin of a particle - are they related?) provides excellent motivation for me to learn about them.

Comment: Rascal, the properties I describe are pretty easy to prove yourself, just look up the multiplication rules. There was a time when physicists were serious about writing everything in quaternions, but time passed. There are very popular in computer graphics. In fact, you might just look up quaternions on this site with the search box in the upper right of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more general approach to constructing a left-invariant vector field on any Lie group.

Let $G$ be a Lie group. A diffeomorphism $f: G \to G$ induces a morphism $df: TG \to TG$ in the following way: Let $x \in G$. Then, an element $\nu$ of $T_xG$ is a map $\nu: \mathcal{A}_x \to \mathbb{R}$ that is linear and satisfies the Liebniz rule. Here, $\mathcal{A}_x$ is the space of germs of smooth functions at $x$ (you can also just think of this as the space of smooth functions defined locally around $x$).

In particular, $df$ is a map from $T_xG$ to $T_{f(x)}G$ defined by 
\begin{equation}
(df(\nu))(h) \ = \ \nu(h \circ f)
\end{equation}
for $h \in \mathcal{A}_x$.

When $G$ is a Lie group, left multiplication is a diffeomorphism. So, pick any vector $v \in T_eG$. Let left multiplication by $g \in G$ be denoted by $L_g: G \to G$. Define the vector field $X_v$ by

\begin{equation}
X_v(g) \ = \ (dL_g)(v). 
\end{equation}

Since left multiplication is smooth, the resulting vector field $X_v: G \to TG$ will also be smooth, though one should check this in local coordinates. Finally, this vector field is left-invariant, since 
\begin{align}
((L_g)_*(X_v))(gh) \ &= \ (dL_g) ((X_v)(h)) \\
                 \ &= \ (dL_g)(dL_h)(v) \\
                 \ &= \ (dL_{gh})(v) \\
                 \ &= \ X_v(gh)
\end{align}

i.e. $(L_g)_*(X_v) = X_v$.

Continuing this line of argument, one can se that in fact every left-invariant vector field on $G$ is determined by its value at the identity and that left-invariant vector fields are in a natural correspondence with elements of $\mathfrak{g}$, the Lie algebra, consisting of elements of $T_eG$ and that the Lie bracket on $\mathfrak{g}$ is induced by the Lie bracket of vector fields, i.e. $[X,Y] = XY - YX$ for $X,Y$ vector fields on $G$.